# Other than $1$, does the sequence $1,12,123,1234,\cdots$ contain a Fibonacci Number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Other than $1$, does the sequence $1,12,123,1234,\dots$ contain  Fibonacci Numbers?

This is sequence [A007908](https://oeis.org/A007908), and the numbers listed in this sequence is obtained by concatenating the first $n$ positive integers.

What I noticed is that some of the Fibonacci Numbers, namely $13, 34, 89,$ and $233$.

$13$ and $233$ are numbers “nearly concatenated” because $12$ and $234$ are both obtained by concatenating $n$ consecutive positive integers and the numbers adjacent to them is a Fibonacci Number.

The only Fibonacci Number that is obtained by concatenating $n$ consecutive positive integers are $34$ and $89$.

A number $n$ can be only a Fibonacci Number if $5n
^{2}\pm4$ is a perfect square.

I used Paridroid to check the values of $n\leq10^{4}$, and so far none of the numbers listed there is a Fibonacci Number.

Comment: Are you just interested in the Smarandache-numbers (where $1$ to $n$ are concattenated) or also in the case that we start with a higher natural number ?

Comment: @Peter: Yes. That’s what I mean.